# Performance loss after applying SMOTE

Tags: r, bayesian, unbalanced-classes, naive-bayes, smote

I'm working on a classification problem, and I've an unbalanced dataset, so I applied SMOTE algorithm in order to balance it.

While I got an increased performance when working with classification trees, the opposite happens when I used the Naive-Bayes classifier. Why is this happening?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352

Comment: As @StephanKolassa notes, class imbalance turns out not to be a problem!